# chronoforms v5 multi file upload...cannot choose multiple files

Tags: file-upload, chronoforms

I am trying to configure this in v5 and cannot find any documentation.  This is what I have so far...

followed the V4 documentation as close as possible, but cannot get the form to allow me to choose multiple files!

Under HTML Render I have Form Tag Attachment = enctype="multipart/form-data"

Under the designer tab I have file field element on the form. Under this I have 
    Field Name = file1[]
    Field ID = file1
    Multiple=Yes

Under the settings tab I have the files upload action in the on submit event. In the files upload action I have
    Enabled=Yes
    Files config = file1:jpg-png-gif-txt
    Array fields = file1

is there anything else I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug and will be fixed in the next update.  Workaround by creating a custom file upload element with the word multiple as a parameter.